# Wiggle the tower

Tags: code-golf, array

Your input is the height map of a tower. The tower is made out of layers, each one being one unit shorter than the one below it. Every layer is completely on top of the previous layer. For example `[1,5,4,3,2]` is a valid input. Here is a visualization:

```
 #
 ##
 ###
 ####
#####

15432
```

Your task is to wiggle the tower. Wiggling works as from top to bottom. For each layer, we first try to shift left.  If we can, we shift left and then stop.  If we can't, we shift the layer to the right and repeat for the next layer. If we reach the bottom layer we stop. The bottom layer doesn't move anywhere. When a layer is shifted, the layers above it also move the same amount in the same direction.

Here is a wiggle, step by step:

```
 #
 ##
 ###
 ####
#####

  #
 ##
 ###
 ####
#####
Top layer couldn't move left, so move right and repeat

   #
  ##
 ###
 ####
#####
Layer 2 couldn't move left, so move right and repeat

    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
Layer 3 couldn't move left, so move right and repeat

   #
  ##
 ###
####
#####
Layer 4 could move left, so the wiggle stops here.
Wiggling would anyway finish at the second lowest layer, since the lowest layer is immovable.
```

This means that if your program got input `[1,5,4,3,2]` it should return `[2,3,4,5,1]`.

Because of the mathematics of tower wiggling, your input is always a permutation of the positive integers up to the array length, and also there are \$2^{n-1}\$ valid inputs (and outputs) for arrays of length \$n\$.

## Test cases (all towers up to \$n=10\$)

```
[1] -> [1]
[1, 2] -> [2, 1] -> [1, 2]
[1, 2, 3] -> [1, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 1] -> [3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> [1, 2, 4, 3] -> [1, 3, 4, 2] -> [1, 4, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 4, 1] -> [2, 4, 3, 1] -> [3, 4, 2, 1] -> [4, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 7, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 7, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 3, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 2, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 3, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 3, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [2, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [3, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 8, 9, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 8, 10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [7, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [9, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Can we assume the input will never contain the same value twice? (as is the case for the test cases)

Comment: @pxeger Yes. The test cases contain every single array of length `<11` that you have to handle. The rules *should* gurantee that the input is always a permutation of the positive integers up to the array length, let me know if there is some detail missing from the rules that would allow non-permutations.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`  becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Why does this occur? Essentially, we can't move the top layer to the left, so we move to the right, then same thing for second layer, etc. until we have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` but are at the bottom layer. The bottom layer cannot be moved to the left nor to the right. Do we just leave it as it is if we reach the bottom layer?

Comment: @ophact Exactly! I'll clarify that in the post.

Comment: Read >1min and know that it's placement of layers representing a binary to increase

Comment: @Jonah the example is correct. [Here](https://pastebin.com/L8DwtnNh) is a step by step visualization of how the tower moves (2->3).

Comment: @Jonah If by "step 5" you mean lines 28-32, then the answer is no. The wiggling process continues, because the layer above moved right. It only ends when layer 4 moves to the left. Perhaps the confusion comes from the fact that in 15432->23451, layers 1,2 and 4 change, while layer 3 doesn't. This is because when a layer moves, the layers on top will "go along" the ride. Here layer 3 first moves right and then layer 4 moves left, resulting in zero net movement.

Comment: @Jonah Yes that's correct, but why would we have 3 steps instead of 4? The number of steps depends on how many layers can be shifted. Here, we can't shift layer 1 left, so we shift it right, and next shift layer 2. Layer 2 can't be shifted left, so shift right, and then shift layer 3. Layer 3 can't move left, so we shift it right, and repeat with layer 4. Layer 4 **can** be shifted left, so we shift it left, and the process ends.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134274/discussion-between-anttip-and-jonah).

Comment: It's not at all clear to me from the description that the input will be a permutation of 1..n. I think you should just say that upfront.

Comment: @DLosc, Agree it's not obvious, but a proof: Start with n ones, and set 1 aside.  Now increment the remaining n-1, so we have n-1 twos.  Set 1 two aside.  Now increment the remaining, so have n-2 threes, etc.  What we set aside is clearly 1,2,3,...n.  Stacking layers, each 1 smaller in width than the last, is identical to this process.

Comment: @AnttiP question about test case `2 3 1` -> `3 2 1`.  I get a different answer when manually going through the shifts: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xDgIhEET7/YpJaLkCbP2ZPYWDBCGBTdSvRxSKS3zlzMvs7txC7@4VhQiKlMKX67ahCVfRsLjAjFwRze5XJn67CoMWohck52Uo08KfZjVunOUkY1hLG7SyqhqPIGvlxF5EymOOaeQiIeYDUnAvRGb8Z9c5HzMncG5PV3v/AA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah if we can move left at a layer, we stop. (It's a bit hidden away in the example ..."Layer 4 could move left, so the wiggle stops here. Wiggling would anyway finish at the second lowest layer...", so it could be made clearer.

Comment: That wasn't clear to me from the text description.  I went ahead and made an edit.  @AnttiP Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: @xiver77 I went ahead and rolled back.  If you are saying Jonathan Allan's answer to my question [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243078/wiggle-the-tower?noredirect=1#comment547433_243078) is incorrect, what is the correct answer to that question?  Also, technically speaking, the OP's original text logically matches my edit, my edit was just more explicit.  But grammatically the entire clause "shift the layer to the right and repeat for the next layer" should only apply "if this is not possible".

Comment: No worries.  I will add back the edit later.

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>126</s> 121 bytes

-5 byte from Neil

```javascript
f=(x,n=x.length,s=n,j,k=(x+'').match(`(.*?)((\\d+,)?${s})\\b(.*)`))=>k?f(x,--n,[s,n],k):j[1]+j[2].split`,`.reverse()+j[4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZ1bb1zHEYTf/Sv4EMBcayWbl90znYDWD5GEiJLpi6xIhiUYBoL8dkVL7tmZrv5q@JIgVO3uOXPpqa6unry7/ev209s/f/vj89MPH3@6@/Ll55vzv7cfbv5@9v7uwy@ff91@uvmwfbf9/etfn3z77ebZf24/v/31/PX5s@@eb87PX7786cl28/wf//30v83Ll2@@/nXzerO5@fH35z9//ZanTz9sX3zafni1/X3zz3cvLl49effi8tWzT3@8/@3z6@3rZ3/e/XX356e7883Xv1@/@vKv118hZ09/PPv6X9@8uNieXT78r8vt2fr3w98e/ml7dnX629UIvTqhr@5hw0cPnzl9ent2Pf7LtXzh9ek7Lx7@UX7j@vTNl@u/95@9Hn/5@GF9ksPvjw@zPdvJv@/qI@7Gp7x8gNQH343PfrWi0uvsxje6OH1Rfcnd@J6n70qvvhvf/nL4rjQgu3EM@kONw7STkeoPBYN3GC8Zv@3ZvqL2OLB7GdurByCO@F4G/XrF6lTsZTYuT1@Kc7SXaTp9r07eXubvavhendW9TGx/WJnuvcz4xfiwuA72shROX60LZC9rZHxeXTl7WTzj86YltZdVdZmfV9faXpZbH1xZhHtZh2lwZXXuZTWmwR2X7b6u3DS4vJ4P67cu6e3ZgtjFLfelrvjrB7jbCkvdDbv1E7BNlrpTrk4/4LbQUnfR6Tdgey11h10PvwFbb6m7r79E3ZZL3ZmX40u4LbvUXXv6GdjOS93R43vAVl/qbh/fQ8PAUiPBVX4PCBFLjRJ9Mmr4WGoESZNRQ8tSo0uaDAk7S408FzIZLiQtNSqdfgnC1VIj1vgqEMqWGs3GV9Ewt9RIJ/MBIXCpUXCcDw2PS42QMh8aOpcaPWU@UlhdamS9LPMBIXepUbdvjhqOlxqR0@aooXqp0TptDgnjS43kujlqiF9qlE@bQ8L/Uk8A3RxyNCz1HNDNMR4bC54cujnskXI4P/BU2Z4194k2OXQanju7hw9NzqSGx9J@/RwfWQ1PrevTj01OtIaH2un3@MBreObtht/j87DhkdhfDo/Lhifm1fhyk9O04YF6@kk@bBuet@P78Vnc8Dge3w@O6oan9XV@Pz7JGx7mffLwoG941qfJQx7QkAqkyas0oSFTuJTJm7CIhkTi9KtMMhryjPEVmYM0pCHjKwJFachSZP6YwTQkMeP8AcFpyHFk/oD/NKRAMn9KjxoypKsyf8yeGhKovvmQXDXkV2nzIfdqSL/S5qvUrCE7082HzK0heUubrxK7htxON1/lfQ2pn24@oYUNmeFF3XwT1tiQOJ5@mEllQ145viVzzoa0c3xLoKQNWalMITPWhqR1nEIgtA05rUwh8N2GlFemUOlwQ0Zc9x@z5YaEedx/QKYb8mnZf8C1G9Jt2X9KxRuy8br/gKk3JOuy/5TIN@Tydf8pz29I9ev@S2lAw0zgkvYfZwkNE4V@@GES0TCPSIcf5hgN04x0@NUUpGEWoocfZigNk5R0@NUEpmEOo4dfzW8apjh6@En60zADgsMPs6OGCVI6/Gry1DB/0sOv5lYN0ys9/CT1aph9weFXM7OGyZkefpK4Nczd4PCTvK5hBgeH35j2NZf5weE3ywoP@Z9LDLdnMflczFPHcNnj/uGj8@QyXH65rJ@26We4DHR3@uF5ghouRz39tk1hw2Wx@@G3bZIbLs/tL@3S4HCZ8PX40vNEOVyufPp5m0qHy6bH97bJdrh8e3xvTsfDZeS7/N42YQ@Xs/fJdil9uKw@TbZL@sPl/WmyURYIpwxcyWTPhYNw2sHpCay0EE5dGF/dig/h9Ifx1VmeCKdQyHxbASOchjHON0sc4VQOmW8WQcLpIDLfIJOEU0quy3xbISWcltI3t5NawqktaXM7MSacHpM2N8o14RQb3dxO0Amn6aTNjZJPONVHNzeKQuF0Id3cVTYKpxxd1s09F5bCaUunh7DSUzj1aXx7K06F06fGt2f5KpyCJVNuBa5wGtc45SyBhVPBZMpZJAunk8mUg4wWTkmr@9sKbeG0tnF/sxQXTo2T/c1iXTi9TvY3yHnhFL26v1nwC6f5yf4GSTCcKlj3N4iG4XTDur9VVgynLF7R/rbCYzjtsR/eTpoMp06mw9uJl@H0y3R4o7wZTuHUw9sJoOE00HR4o0QaTiXVwxtF1HA6qh7eVWYNp7TC4e2E2HBabDq8UaoNp9bq4Y1ibjg9Vw/vKveGU3zh8EZBOJwmrId3lYzDqcZweFdROZyuDIe3yM7hlOcLPLznwnQ4bfr0HFa6DqdejwNgxe1w@vY4ACx/h1PAZdatQB5OIx9nnSX0cCq6zDqL7OF0dpl1kOHDKfF1i1uhPpxWP25xlvLDqfmyxVnsD6f3yxaHckC4ikDd4lwwCFczkC0OJYVwVYW6xaHoEK7uULe4liXCVSbw/LaFi3C1i/H85tJGuOqGnN9c/AhX/5DzG8oj4Sok9fzmAkq4Goqc31BiCVdlqec3FGHC1WHq@a1lmnCVGjy/uZATrpYj5zeUesJVe@r5DcWgcPWgen5ruShcxQjPbygohasp1fNbS07hqk54fmtRKlxdCs/vVLYKV7m6NOe3LWyFq2315NuVvsJVv1Ly7Ypj4epjKfnG8lm4Cpom367AFq7GlpJvLMGFq8Jp8o1FunB1Ok2@axkvXCUPkm9X6AtX60vJN5YCw1UDNfnGYmG4eqEm37WcGK6iCMk3FhzD1Rw1@a4lyXBVSUi@a9EyXN0Skm8pa4arbHLy7Qqf4WqfKfnG0mi46qgm31g8DVc/1eS7llfDVVgh@cYCbLgarCbftUQbrkoLyXct4oar40LyLWXecJVeTr6xEByuFqzJdy0Vh6sWQ/Jdi8nh6smQfEu5OVzFmZPvWpAOV5OG5FtK1uGq1px8S1E7XO2ak@@x7B2Tyjcn348Uxg/170lt/Ounf5h//OKHR0voB0ibQO6/4tFK@wG1TCDHb5kV5O8fZAJZH@TRuv0BuJ9Ajl80K@8fn8VC@rPMXAD3gzKBrIMyMQusg@Igw6A86ik4YHcTyPG7ZtaD4@NYSH@cmUPhOC4W0sfFGhn6uDAkjcvM73C/WCaQdbFMbBHrYnGQYbFM3BPrYnGQYbE4k8WwWBCSF8ujXowD/HoCOX7dzLJxfCIL6U80c3Ych8ZC@tBYA0gfGoakoZn5RI7rxUL6erF2kr5eGJLWi3Wd9PXCkLRe2JyS1gtAdL3MPCz3wWUCWYPLxOqyBhcHGYLLxBGzBhcHGYKLM84MwQUhObhM/DVrcHGQIbg4G84QXBCSg4tz6wzBBSE5uKCpJweXCinB5VHvz@ETVxPI8RtnFqHjQ1lIf6iZk@g4OhbSR8cajvroMCSNzsyXdFwyFtKXjLUv9SXDkLRkrMupLxmGpCXDZqi0ZACiS2bmmTrGFwvp8cVaq3p8YUiKL9aB1eMLQ1J8YaNWii8A0fhi/Vw9vjAkxRe2faX4AhCNL@wOS/EFIBpfwESm8UUhEF9mXrN78jKBrORlYklbyYuDDORl4lxbyYuDDOTFGdwG8oKQTF4mPriVvDjIQF6cXW4gLwjJ5MW56gbygpBMXtB8l8lLhRTyMvHoreTFQQby4qx8A3lBSCYvzvE3kBeEZPKCxsBMXiqkkBfnHxzIC0IyeUGbYSYvFVLIC7oRM3mpkEJeqmmxkBeBEHl51Nt4@NDlBHL80pkF8vhcFtKfa@aUPA6QhfQBsobKPkAMSQM0810eV42F9FVj7Zl91TAkrRrr4uyrhiFp1bDZM60agOiqmXlCjyHGQnqIsdbRHmIYkkKMdZj2EMOQFGLYiJpCDEA0xFi/ag8xDEkhhm2tKcQAREMMu19TiAGIhhgwyWqIUQiEmJmX9shfLKTzF2u57fyFIYm/WGdu5y8MSfyFDbyJvwBE@Yv1@Xb@wpDEX9gOnPgLQJS/sGs48ReAKH8Bc7HyF4UAf7Ee5M5fGJL4C1uVE38BiPIXdjQn/gIQ5S9gfFb@ohDgL@yPTvwFIMpfwEat/EUhwF/Aba38RSHAX9SUDfwlQZi/zLzb9@LLBLKKLxOL9yq@OMggvkyc4Kv44iCD@OIM44P4gpAsvkx85av44iCD@OLs54P4gpAsvjiX@iC@ICSLL2hmz@JLhRTxZeJ5X8UXBxnEF2eNH8QXhGTxxTnoB/EFIVl8QaN9Fl8qpIgvzo8/iC8IyeIL2vaz@FIhRXxBd38WXyqkiC@1CaCILwIh8WXSK7CKLw4yiC@upWAQXxCSxRfXeTCILwjJ4gs2KGTxpUKK@OL6GAbxBSFZfMF2hyy@VEgRX7ArIosvFVLEl9o8UcQXgZD44nosBvEFIVl8wVaMLL5USBFfsGMjiy8VUsSX2thRxBeBkPiC/R9ZfKmQIr7UNpEivgiExJfaTVLEF4GQ@CJNJyS@jBAjvjzem/LDpD@lP9qsheX4aBbSH23W6XIcIwvpY2QbYvoYMSSN0axv5rhwLKQvHNte0xcOQ9LCsV04feEwJC0cbtZJCwcgunBmPT3HKGMhPcrY1p8eZRiSooztEOpRhiEpynAjUYoyANEoY/uNepRhSIoy3JaUogxANMpw91KKMgDRKANNThplFAJRZtYLdaQwFtIpjG2Z6hSGIYnC2M6qTmEYkigMN2AlCgMQpTC2T6tTGIYkCsPtXInCAEQpDHd9JQoDEKUw0BymFEYhQGFsD1mnMAxJFIZbzRKFAYhSGO5ISxQGIEphoHFNKYxCgMJwf1uiMABRCgNtcEphFAIUBrrllMIoBCiMNtUBhUkQpjCz3ruj/mIhXX@xLXpdf2FI0l9sJ1/XXxiS9Bdu@Ev6C0BUf7F9gV1/YUjSX7h9MOkvAFH9hbsMk/4CENVfoBlR9ReFgP5iexa7/sKQpL9wa2PSXwCi@gt3QCb9BSCqv0CjpOovCgH9hfspk/4CENVfoO1S9ReFgP4C3ZmqvygE9Bdt4gT9JUFYf7G9nl1/YUjSX7glNOkvAFH9hTtHk/4CENVfoMFU9ReFgP7CfahJfwGI6i/Qrqr6i0JAf4GuVtVfFAL6iza/gv6SIKy/cI9s0l8AovoLtNKq/qIQ0F@g41b1F4WA/qKNuaC/JAjrL9C/q/qLQkB/0TZf0F8ShPUX7QYG/SVBWH9JTcOsv3SI1V9mvcX35pcJZDW/TFqQV/OLgwzml0mn8mp@cZDB/OIamgfzC0Ky@WXS97yaXxxkML@49ujB/IKQbH5xXdSD@QUh2fyCzdbZ/FIhxfwy6clezS8OMphfXOv2YH5BSDa/uA7vwfyCkGx@wUbwbH6pkGJ@cf3ig/kFIdn8gm3l2fxSIcX8gt3n2fxSIcX8UpvUi/lFIGR@mfSyr@YXBxnML67lfTC/ICSbX1xn/GB@QUg2v2ADfTa/VEgxv7g@@8H8gpBsfsF2/Gx@qZBifsGu/Wx@qZBifqnN/cX8IhAyv7g7AAbzC0Ky@QWvCsjmlwop5he8USCbXyqkmF/qxQPF/CIQMr/g/QTZ/FIhxfxSrzEo5heBkPml3nZQzC8CIfOLXIpA5pcRYswvk7sTVvOLgwzmF3fFwmB@QUg2v7ibGAbzC0Ky@QUvbMjmlwop5hd3r8NgfkFINr/g9Q/Z/FIhxfyCt0Rk80uFFPNLvUyimF8EQuYXd@fEYH5BSDa/4NUU2fxSIcX8gjdYZPNLhRTzS73oophfBELmF7wPI5tfKqSYX@q1GcX8IhAyv9TbNYr5RSBkfpFLOMj8MkKM@cXd1TGYXxCSzS94pUc2v1RIMb/gzR/Z/FIhxfxSLwgp5heBkPkF7xHJ5pcKKeaXet1IMb8IhMwv9VaSYn4RCJlf5PISMr@MEGN@wTtOsvmlQor5pV6FUswvAiHzS70xpZhfBELmF7lYhcwvI8SYX@r9K8X8IhAyv8g1LWR@GSHG/CK3uZD5ZYQY88t46Ysxv/SLX6z55fG7Ye7vf/nm8P9g/8f727d359@fv3zx7LvnL19tDp87f35z@t@b73/Znp3/e3u7fbO5@fHtxw@fPr6/e/b@4y/ntzd3f92@P7/dbM9@vv/PNw9/eHP8w83Nm83my/8B)

Reverse `(_,)n,n-1,n-2,...,n-k` which seems correct but long

Comment: Can you use `.split\`,\`` instead of `.match(/\d+/g)`?

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 57 bytes

```
def f(L):a=L.argmax();m=L>=(a and L[a-1]);L[m]=L[m][::-1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZ1LblzXEYbnWkXDIzJoCear720Z9NyAdkBoQECSQ0WiCFEOokk2koknyTRryDKS1YTN7j5V_19fXWfgWKqvu8-rXv85Qf7xr4fv3_785f733__527cPL-f_bt-9_7D6cPLm9PXt9ZtXt19__Xz7t5PTnz5fv_n5-uR2dXv_bvXm5vbl2dvTn97cfH57vfvHzevXT39x-IL_3H1--PL12-rx--OLw7_e__b54fvq9nF1__Diw5evq7vV3f3O_urx27u7-1df39---3R3__7x5PT1i9Vq9cvqenXzp8-3Dyf3D08j-Hr7fb37w_u_3n5a3716fPh09-3kh9XLn1c_nJ6evt194uPTJ365-fH538cP_HJz9vrt8xc-_ef28fH900huP306-XDy8fSJ-Xh9ffLx9fXd6emLh693909f-WRcffnLD6f7ifz-v7__--bs7e53nv7rxc3ZenW-_9P5enX8-93f7U3r1cX4u4uMXgz64hlLH919Znx6vbrMlkv7wsvxnWd7o_3G5fjm86M9fvYy__Lhwz6S3e_nwaxXV2a_qkO8yqM83yN14Fd57BdHSqZzlWd0Nr6oTvIqz3N8l0z9Ks_-PH2XLMhVXoMYVF6mK1upGBQs3m69bP3Wq02lNriwG1vbiz2IK76xRb88sr4VG9uN8_GluEcb26bxvb55G9u_i_S9vqsb29gYrG33xnb8LA8Wz8HGjsL4aj8gGzsjebx-cjZ2ePJ45Uht7FSd63j9rG3suMXi2iHc2DmUxbXTubHTKIubj-2mnlxZXD7Pu_Nbj_R6NSE7dcd9qif-co93rjBVb7g6fgLcZKqecjF-oHOhqXrR-A1wr6l62GX6DXC9qXpfTKK65VQ98zxPonPZqXrt-Blw56l6dJ4HuPpUvT3Pw8PAmIcY8jwgREw1SsRm1PAx1Qgim1FDy1Sji2yGhZ0pO8cwyGZ0IWmqUWn8EoSrqUasPBUIZVONZnkqHubGVMSQpwIhcKpRMO-Hh8exH2LI--Ghc-yHGPJ-SFjN-xEG2w8IuVONuuEcNRxPNSKLc9RQPdVoLc5hYTycIxvEOWqIn2qUF-ew8B_OkQ3iHJYawjmyQZwjpw1xjmFw52hTyi5_YFZZr-buE_NC0pkx71ztP7SQk2ZMS5vj5zhlzZi1LsePLWS0GZPa-D1OeDPmvKv0e5wPZ0yJMTlMlzNmzIs8uYVsOmNCHT_JyXbGfJvnx7l4xnSc5wepeszPbXl-nMlnTOaxeZjoZ8z1snlYB8xYCsjm1TJhzv6XbbJ5C1XEjIXE-FUuMmasM_IUuQaZsQzJU4QSZUzRbXmKXMHMWMTk_YMCZ-yf2_L-Qf0z9s9tef-8PMr7JzbbP66eZiygwvmwuJqxvhLnw9prxvJLnK-WZuF8ZhPnw8ptxuJNnK8WduF8ZhPnq3VfOJ_ZxPmsLBTnyzZ3voWqccbCcfwwF5Uz1pV5llxzzlh25llCSTpm6bY8S65YZyxa8xZCQTu20G15C6HeHVvotryFXg7nLRSbbSFXyzMWzNn_oJge_ue27H9Qaw__c1v2Py_Fs_-JzfwPKvXhf27L_ueFfPY_sZn_eZ2f_U9s5n_SBpj_ha36H3cJMzYKkfywiZixj5Dkhz3GjG2GJL_agkTyM5skP-xQZmxSJPnVBiaSn9kk-dX-JpKf2ST5WfsjyS_bPPlhdzRjgyTJrzZPkfzMJsmv9laR_Mwmyc9aL0l-2ebJr3ZmkfzMJsnPGjdJftnmyc_6Okl-2ebJL7d9nvyGDZLfUle46_-6xnC92i58brtebB2fzNw9bvYf7czT8dPcX07HT7ft53a_AGjejs2o5k36be5Rx2-3Lez-t9k8frttcrdr6mUv86TRHJNG8zafeDNf6by5Vx4_37bS-59n8_j5ttnez5vNY97cjo95gznPu23Yt2vqvWWz0RybjeZt9l4zy2ajeZv928yy2dUsm71eFA62qAHkqbfSwn4EbB4jaMWH_dTZPKbO8sSYOpjz1FsBY7_fbB77zRLH2G8w5_1mEWTsN5jzfoNMkvfbzbbfrZCyXZMmIs6N5nBuNIdzV7M4N5rDuatZnLuaxbnXjaCzHVmwmsO5q1mcu5rFudckCoVzV7M497rIRuLcZnbnXi8KS1vUiPLsW-lpPwg2j0G04tR-9mwes2f5aswezHn2rcC133I2jy1nCWxsOZjzlrNINrYczHnLQUbLW-5m2_JWaNv7N5uHf7MUN_wbzNm_Wawb_g3m7N8g52X_drP5Nwt-w7_BnP0bJMHs3242_wbRMPu3m82_XVY0_xZz9e9WeNyuSUOU5I3mSN5ojuRdzZK80RzJu5oleVezJG8ze_JGcyTvapbkXc2SvM3sybuaJXmb2ZO3mT15ZzMkbzRH8q5mSd7VLMnbzJ68q1mSt5k9eZvZk3c2Q_KuZkneZvbkbWZP3tkMydvMnryzGZJ3NkPyHmZuvjtteoyjla7342DzGEcrbu8XgM1jAVj-HgsA5rwArUC-33U2j11nCX3sOpjzrrPIPnYdzHnXQYbPu-5m2_VWqN-7OJuHi7OUP1wczNnFWewfLg7m7OJwHZBd3M3m4nxhMFwczNnF4Uohu7ibzcXh0iG7uJvNxf1awlxczNXF24uLff5m88jffLUx8jeYc_7my4-Rv8Gc8zdcj-T87WbL33yBMvI3mHP-hiuWnL_dbPkbLmFy_naz5W-_prH8Leaav_kiZ-RvMOf8DVc9OX-72fI3XAbl_O1my99-XWT5W8w1f8OFUs7fbrb87VdOlr_FXPO3X0pZ_hZzzd9ybVXzd5gxf7cXW9t1c7cVzXd39XVovtEczXd3OXZovtEczTden0XzXc3SfHcXbIfmG83RfOMVXDTf1SzNN17SRfNdzdJ812s8ab7N7M13d9F3aL7RHM03XgVG813N0nzjZWE039UszXe9TpTm28zefOOFYzTf1SzNd72SlObbzN5810tLab7N7M23XWt6853N0Hx3F5-H5hvN0Xzj1Wg039UszTdenkbzXc3SfNfrVWm-zezNN17ARvNdzdJ81ytaab7N7M13vcSV5tvM3nzbNa8339kMzTdeBEfzXc3SfNerYmm-zezNd71MlubbzN5823WzN9_ZDM13vZCW5tvM3nzblbU339kMzbddanvznc3QfOdrb2i-h5mb7z-4GH_6yqW78adP_7j88bMf1390hb5D2mv06fAVC8g8vqW9bZ_HtyxdyD8PZAE5DqRDpjyW9u4-xrJ0vX8YS4vEWJZeATwvygJyXJQOSYvSIWlRENnYurTvCmI4S08PDsNpkRjO0guFw7q0SKxL-5Ah1oURWZel9w7Ph2UBOR6WDkmHpUPSYUFED0uHpMOCiB4WRPSwVKQEl3X_HiNGtPRk4zCiFokRLb3sOCxNi8TStA9AYmkYkaVZeidyOC8tEuelfU4S54UROS_tq5M4L4zIeeHHKXJeAPHzsvSG5Tm4LCDH4NIhKbh0SAouiGhw6ZAUXBDR4IKIBpeKlODSISm4IKLBBRENLhUpwQURDS4VKcGlIiW4rP_o7c_uE-37nxjU0hOhw6BaJAa19JLosDotEqvTPjiK1WFEVmfpXdLhyLRIHJn2-VIcGUbkyLSvnOLIMCJHhh9DyZEBxI_M0pupQ3xpkYgv7dOqiC-MSHxpX2BFfGFE4gs_1JL4AojHl_Y9V8QXRiS-8LMviS-AeHzh12ESXwDx-AKPyDy-OALxZemt2XPxsoAci5cOScVLh6TiBREtXjokFS-IaPGCiBYvFSnFS4ek4gURLV4Q0eKlIqV4QUSLl4qU4qUipXgxhIqXDknFCyJavCCixUtFSvGCiBYvFSnFS0VK8WIIFS-IaPFSkVK8VKQUL4ZQ8VKRUrwYQsWLIVS8ZKQRX9b9-8YY19ITyMO4WiTGtfRS8rBALRIL1D6ojAViRBZo6d3l4dS0SJya9nlmnBpG5NS0rzjj1DAip4Yfe8qpAcRPzdKb0EOIaZEIMe3T0QgxjEiIaV-YRohhREIMP0SVEAOIh5j2vWqEGEYkxPCzVgkxgHiI4devEmIA8RADj2Q9xDgCIWbpLe2hfmmRqF_aJ7dRvzAi9Uv7MjfqF0akfuEHvFK_AOL1S_vON-oXRqR-4efAUr8A4vULvxqW-gUQr1_gcbHXL45A_dK-QY76hRGpX_ipstQvgHj9wi-apX4BxOsXePjs9YsjUL_w-2ipXwDx-gWeUXv94gjUL_Da2usXR6B-8UfZUL8IwvXL0tvtZ_FlATmKLx2SxJcOSeILIiq-dEgSXxBR8QURFV8qUsSXDkniCyIqviCi4ktFiviCiIovFSniS0WK-GIIiS8dksQXRFR8QUTFl4oU8QURFV8qUsSXihTxxRASXxBR8aUiRXypSBFfDCHxpSJFfDGExBdDSHzJSCO-dEgSXxBR8QURFV8qUsQXRFR8qUgRXypSxBdDSHxBRMWXihTxpSJFfDGExJeKFPHFEBJfDCHxJSON-IKIii8VKeJLRYr4YgiJLxUp4oshJL4YQuJLRhrxpSJFfDGExBdDSHzJSCO-GELiS0Ya8SUjjfgykP7xy7r_36fE0FokhtYiMTRGZI1aJNaIEVkjRmSNAPGD0yJxcBiRg8OIHBxA_OAwIgcHED84gPjBcQSiTItElGFEogwjEmUA8SjDiEQZQDzKAOJRxhGIMoxIlAHEowwgHmUcgSgDiEcZRyDKOAJRRhAuYVokShhGpIRhREoYQLyEYURKGEC8hAHESxhHoIRhREoYQLyEAcRLGEeghAHESxhHoIRxBEoYQbiEYURKGEC8hAHESxhHoIQBxEsYR6CEcQRKGEG4hAHESxhHoIRxBEoYQbiEcQRKGEG4hBGES5hAWv2lRUJ_YUT0F0ZEfwHE9RdGRH8BxPUXQFx_cQT0F0ZEfwHE9RdAXH9xBPQXQFx_cQT0F0dAfxGE9RdGRH8BxPUXQFx_cQT0F0Bcf3EE9BdHQH8RhPUXQFx_cQT0F0dAfxGE9RdHQH8RhPUXQVh_CaTVXxgR_QUQ118Acf3FEdBfAHH9xRHQXxwB_UUQ1l8Acf3FEdBfHAH9RRDWXxwB_UUQ1l8EYf0lkFZ_AcT1F0dAf3EE9BdBWH9xBPQXQVh_EYT1l0Ba_cUR0F8EYf1FENZfAmn1F0FYfwmk1V8CafWXA9KKL-cLyOFLWyTG1SIxLkZkgVokFogRWSBGZIEA8VPTInFqGJFTw4icGkD81DAipwYQPzWA-KlxBEJMi0SIYURCDCMSYgDxEMOIhBhAPMQA4iHGEQgxjEiIAcRDDCAeYhyBEAOIhxhHIMQ4AiFGEK5fWiTqF0akfmFE6hdAvH5hROoXQLx-AcTrF0egfmFE6hdAvH4BxOsXR6B-AcTrF0egfnEE6hdBuH5hROoXQLx-AcTrF0egfgHE6xdHoH5xBOoXQbh-AcTrF0egfnEE6hdBuH5xBOoXQbh-EYTrl0Ba8aVFQnxhRMQXRkR8AcTFF0ZEfAHExRdAXHxxBMQXRkR8AcTFF0BcfHEExBdAXHxxBMQXR0B8EYTFF0ZEfAHExRdAXHxxBMQXQFx8cQTEF0dAfBGExRdAXHxxBMQXR0B8EYTFF0dAfBGExRdBWHwJpBVfGBHxBRAXXwBx8cUREF8AcfHFERBfHAHxRRAWXwBx8cUREF8cAfFFEBZfHAHxRRAWXwRh8SWQVnwBxMUXR0B8cQTEF0FYfHEExBdBWHwRhMWXQFrxxREQXwRh8UUQFl8CacUXQVh8CaQVXwJpxZeEPP-hUWHevtj_H9f_Hw)

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 59 bytes

```
def f(L):a=L.argmax();m=a and L[a-1];b=L>=m;L[b]=L[b][::-1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZ1LblvZEYbnXgXRIylgG60X76UN9bwB70DwQIHtRI4tC5Y7iCfZSCY9SaZZQ5aRrCaiSJ6q_6-vbmfQabs-kudVr_-cIP_418P3b3_-cv_bb__89duHH-f_vn73_sPqw8mb01e3129e3n790-fbv52cvv58fbu6vX-3enNz--PZ29d_vH7z8_Xn129u_vj2evePm1evnv768BX_ufv88OXrt9Xj98cXh3-9__Xzw_fV7ePq_uHFhy9fV3eru_ud_eXjt3d39y-_vr999-nu_v3jyemrF6vV6pfV9ermD59vH07uH57G8PX2-3r3h_d_vf20vnv5-PDp7tvJD6sff179cHp6-nb3iY9Pn_jl5qfnfx8_8MvN2au3z1_49J_bx8f3TyO5_fTp5MPJx9Mn5uP19cnHV9d3p6cvHr7e3T995ZNx9eUvP5zuJ_Lb__7-75uzt7vfefqvFzdn69X5_k_n69Xx73d_tzetVxfj7y4yejHoi2csfXT3mfHp9eoyWy7tCy_Hd57tjfYbl-Obz4_2-NnL_MuHD_tIdr-fB7NeXZn9qg7xKo_yfI_UgV_lsV8cKZnOVZ7R2fiiOsmrPM_xXTL1qzz78_RdsiBXeQ1iUHmZrmylYlCweLv1svVbrzaV2uDCbmxtL_YgrvjGFv3yyPpWbGw3zseX4h5tbJvG9_rmbWz_LtL3-q5ubGNjsLbdG9vxszxYPAcbOwrjq_2AbOyM5PH6ydnY4cnjlSO1sVN1ruP1s7ax4xaLa4dwY-dQFtdO58ZOoyxuPrabenJlcfk8785vPdLr1YTs1B33qZ74yz3eucJUveHq-Alwk6l6ysX4gc6FpupF4zfAvabqYZfpN8D1pup9MYnqllP1zPM8ic5lp-q142fAnafq0Xke4OpT9fY8Dw8DYx5iyPOAEDHVKBGbUcPHVCOIbEYNLVONLrIZFnam7BzDIJvRhaSpRqXxSxCuphqx8lQglE01muWpeJgbUxFDngqEwKlGwbwfHh7Hfogh74eHzrEfYsj7IWE170cYbD8g5E416oZz1HA81YgszlFD9VSjtTiHhfFwjmwQ56ghfqpRXpzDwn84RzaIc1hqCOfIBnGOnDbEOYbBnaNNKbv8gVllvZq7T8wLSWfGvHO1_9BCTpoxLW2On-OUNWPWuhw_tpDRZkxq4_c44c2Y867S73E-nDElxuQwXc6YMS_y5Bay6YwJdfwkJ9sZ822eH-fiGdNxnh-k6jE_t-X5cSafMZnH5mGinzHXy-ZhHTBjKSCbV8uEOftftsnmLVQRMxYS41e5yJixzshT5BpkxjIkTxFKlDFFt-UpcgUzYxGT9w8KnLF_bsv7B_XP2D-35f3z8ijvn9hs_7h6mrGACufD4mrG-kqcD2uvGcsvcb5amoXzmU2cDyu3GYs3cb5a2IXzmU2cr9Z94XxmE-ezslCcL9vc-RaqxhkLx_HDXFTOWFfmWXLNOWPZmWcJJemYpdvyLLlinbFozVsIBe3YQrflLYR6d2yh2_IWejmct1BstoVcLc9YMGf_g2J6-J_bsv9BrT38z23Z_7wUz_4nNvM_qNSH_7kt-58X8tn_xGb-53V-9j-xmf9JG2D-F7bqf9wlzNgoRPLDJmLGPkKSH_YYM7YZkvxqCxLJz2yS_LBDmbFJkeRXG5hIfmaT5Ff7m0h-ZpPkZ-2PJL9s8-SH3dGMDZIkv9o8RfIzmyS_2ltF8jObJD9rvST5ZZsnv9qZRfIzmyQ_a9wk-WWbJz_r6yT5ZZsnv9z2efIbNkh-S13hrv_rGsP1arvwue16sXV8MnP3uNl_tDNPx09zfzkdP922n9v9AqB5Ozajmjfpt7lHHb_dtrD732bz-O22yd2uqZe9zJNGc0wazdt84s18pfPmXnn8fNtK73-ezePn22Z7P282j3lzOz7mDeY877Zh366p95bNRnNsNpq32XvNLJuN5m32bzPLZlezbPZ6UTjYogaQp95KC_sRsHmMoBUf9lNn85g6yxNj6mDOU28FjP1-s3nsN0scY7_BnPebRZCx32DO-w0ySd5vN9t-t0LKdk2aiDg3msO50RzOXc3i3GgO565mce5qFudeN4LOdmTBag7nrmZx7moW516TKBTOXc3i3OsiG4lzm9mde70oLG1RI8qzb6Wn_SDYPAbRilP72bN5zJ7lqzF7MOfZtwLXfsvZPLacJbCx5WDOW84i2dhyMOctBxktb7mbbctboW3v32we_s1S3PBvMGf_ZrFu-DeYs3-DnJf9283m3yz4Df8Gc_ZvkASzf7vZ_BtEw-zfbjb_dlnR_FvM1b9b4XG7Jg1RkjeaI3mjOZJ3NUvyRnMk72qW5F3NkrzN7MkbzZG8q1mSdzVL8jazJ-9qluRtZk_eZvbknc2QvNEcybuaJXlXsyRvM3vyrmZJ3mb25G1mT97ZDMm7miV5m9mTt5k9eWczJG8ze_LOZkje2QzJe5i5-e606TGOVrrej4PNYxytuL1fADaPBWD5eywAmPMCtAL5ftfZPHadJfSx62DOu84i-9h1MOddBxk-77qbbddboX7v4mweLs5S_nBxMGcXZ7F_uDiYs4vDdUB2cTebi_OFwXBxMGcXhyuF7OJuNheHS4fs4m42F_drCXNxMVcXby8u9vmbzSN_89XGyN9gzvmbLz9G_gZzzt9wPZLzt5stf_MFysjfYM75G65Ycv52s-VvuITJ-dvNlr_9msbyt5hr_uaLnJG_wZzzN1z15PztZsvfcBmU87ebLX_7dZHlbzHX_A0XSjl_u9nyt185Wf4Wc83ffill-VvMNX_LtVXN32HG_N1ebG3Xzd1WNN_d1deh-UZzNN_d5dih-UZzNN94fRbNdzVL891dsB2abzRH841XcNF8V7M033hJF813NUvzXa_xpPk2szff3UXfoflGczTfeBUYzXc1S_ONl4XRfFezNN_1OlGabzN7840XjtF8V7M03_VKUppvM3vzXS8tpfk2szffdq3pzXc2Q_PdXXwemm80R_ONV6PRfFezNN94eRrNdzVL812vV6X5NrM333gBG813NUvzXa9opfk2szff9RJXmm8ze_Nt17zefGczNN94ERzNdzVL812viqX5NrM33_UyWZpvM3vzbdfN3nxnMzTf9UJamm8ze_NtV9befGczNN92qe3NdzZD852vvaH5HmZuvn_nYvzpK5fuxp8-_dPyx89-Wv_eFfoOaa_Rp8NXLCDz-Jb2tn0e37J0If88kAXkOJAOmfJY2rv7GMvS9f5hLC0SY1l6BfC8KAvIcVE6JC1Kh6RFQWRj69K-K4jhLD09OAynRWI4Sy8UDuvSIrEu7UOGWBdGZF2W3js8H5YF5HhYOiQdlg5JhwURPSwdkg4LInpYENHDUpESXNb9e4wY0dKTjcOIWiRGtPSy47A0LRJL0z4AiaVhRJZm6Z3I4by0SJyX9jlJnBdG5Ly0r07ivDAi54Ufp8h5AcTPy9IblufgsoAcg0uHpODSISm4IKLBpUNScEFEgwsiGlwqUoJLh6TggogGF0Q0uFSkBBdENLhUpASXipTgsv69tz-7T7Tvf2JQS0-EDoNqkRjU0kuiw-q0SKxO--AoVocRWZ2ld0mHI9MicWTa50txZBiRI9O-coojw4gcGX4MJUcGED8yS2-mDvGlRSK-tE-rIr4wIvGlfYEV8YURiS_8UEviCyAeX9r3XBFfGJH4ws--JL4A4vGFX4dJfAHE4ws8IvP44gjEl6W3Zs_FywJyLF46JBUvHZKKF0S0eOmQVLwgosULIlq8VKQULx2SihdEtHhBRIuXipTiBREtXipSipeKlOLFECpeOiQVL4ho8YKIFi8VKcULIlq8VKQULxUpxYshVLwgosVLRUrxUpFSvBhCxUtFSvFiCBUvhlDxkpFGfFn37xtjXEtPIA_japEY19JLycMCtUgsUPugMhaIEVmgpXeXh1PTInFq2ueZcWoYkVPTvuKMU8OInBp-7CmnBhA_NUtvQg8hpkUixLRPRyPEMCIhpn1hGiGGEQkx_BBVQgwgHmLa96oRYhiREMPPWiXEAOIhhl-_SogBxEMMPJL1EOMIhJilt7SH-qVFon5pn9xG_cKI1C_ty9yoXxiR-oUf8Er9AojXL-0736hfGJH6hZ8DS_0CiNcv_GpY6hdAvH6Bx8VevzgC9Uv7BjnqF0akfuGnylK_AOL1C79olvoFEK9f4OGz1y-OQP3C76OlfgHE6xd4Ru31iyNQv8Bra69fHIH6xR9lQ_0iCNcvS2-3n8WXBeQovnRIEl86JIkviKj40iFJfEFExRdEVHypSBFfOiSJL4io-IKIii8VKeILIiq-VKSILxUp4oshJL50SBJfEFHxBREVXypSxBdEVHypSBFfKlLEF0NIfEFExZeKFPGlIkV8MYTEl4oU8cUQEl8MIfElI4340iFJfEFExRdEVHypSBFfEFHxpSJFfKlIEV8MIfEFERVfKlLEl4oU8cUQEl8qUsQXQ0h8MYTEl4w04gsiKr5UpIgvFSniiyEkvlSkiC-GkPhiCIkvGWnEl4oU8cUQEl8MIfElI434YgiJLxlpxJeMNOLLQPrHL-v-f58SQ2uRGFqLxNAYkTVqkVgjRmSNGJE1AsQPTovEwWFEDg4jcnAA8YPDiBwcQPzgAOIHxxGIMi0SUYYRiTKMSJQBxKMMIxJlAPEoA4hHGUcgyjAiUQYQjzKAeJRxBKIMIB5lHIEo4whEGUG4hGmRKGEYkRKGESlhAPEShhEpYQDxEgYQL2EcgRKGESlhAPESBhAvYRyBEgYQL2EcgRLGEShhBOEShhEpYQDxEgYQL2EcgRIGEC9hHIESxhEoYQThEgYQL2EcgRLGEShhBOESxhEoYQThEkYQLmECafWXFgn9hRHRXxgR_QUQ118YEf0FENdfAHH9xRHQXxgR_QUQ118Acf3FEdBfAHH9xRHQXxwB_UUQ1l8YEf0FENdfAHH9xRHQXwBx_cUR0F8cAf1FENZfAHH9xRHQXxwB_UUQ1l8cAf1FENZfBGH9JZBWf2FE9BdAXH8BxPUXR0B_AcT1F0dAf3EE9BdBWH8BxPUXR0B_cQT0F0FYf3EE9BdBWH8RhPWXQFr9BRDXXxwB_cUR0F8EYf3FEdBfBGH9RRDWXwJp9RdHQH8RhPUXQVh_CaTVXwRh_SWQVn8JpNVfDkgrvpwvIIcvbZEYV4vEuBiRBWqRWCBGZIEYkQUCxE9Ni8SpYURODSNyagDxU8OInBpA_NQA4qfGEQgxLRIhhhEJMYxIiAHEQwwjEmIA8RADiIcYRyDEMCIhBhAPMYB4iHEEQgwgHmIcgRDjCIQYQbh-aZGoXxiR-oURqV8A8fqFEalfAPH6BRCvXxyB-oURqV8A8foFEK9fHIH6BRCvXxyB-sURqF8E4fqFEalfAPH6BRCvXxyB-gUQr18cgfrFEahfBOH6BRCvXxyB-sURqF8E4frFEahfBOH6RRCuXwJpxZcWCfGFERFfGBHxBRAXXxgR8QUQF18AcfHFERBfGBHxBRAXXwBx8cUREF8AcfHFERBfHAHxRRAWXxgR8QUQF18AcfHFERBfAHHxxREQXxwB8UUQFl8AcfHFERBfHAHxRRAWXxwB8UUQFl8EYfElkFZ8YUTEF0BcfAHExRdHQHwBxMUXR0B8cQTEF0FYfAHExRdHQHxxBMQXQVh8cQTEF0FYfBGExZdAWvEFEBdfHAHxxREQXwRh8cUREF8EYfFFEBZfAmnFF0dAfBGExRdBWHwJpBVfBGHxJZBWfAmkFV8S8vyHRoV5-2L_f1z_fw)

Port of @l4m2's JS.

#### Stupid [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 122 bytes

```
def f(L,i=-2):
 a,*b=L.argsort()[i:];b.sort()
 if[a]<b:L[[a,*b]]=L[[*b,a]]
 else:L[[*b,a]]=L[[a,*b]];-i<len(L)and f(L,i-1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZ1LblzXEYbnXEXDI9K4EsxX96VsZm5AOyA4oCDKoSJThCgHUAbZSCaeJNOsIctIVhM2u3mq_r--us4kkurr7vOq139OkH_86-Hb1z9_vv_993_-9vXDq_m_f3t_-2H14fDtdHf56uTozcHqZvr-3eXb1zdffnn8_OXr4dHV3ZvrH9-93v3lYHX34erm-qd3b95eXW3J6-vLpz99_266ub4-WN1-erx9M_5-OZgfX9399On2_vDt0c39-92vvTo-2o_gP3e_Pjx9-erx2-PB_o_3v_368G1187i6fzj48PnL6m51d7-1v378-v7u_vWX25v3n-7ubx8PtwNerX5eXa6uvv_15uHw_uFp4F9uvk3bv9z-9ebTdPf68eHT3dfD71av_rT67ujo6Hr7iY9Pn_j56ofnP48f-Pnq-M318xc-_efm8fH2aSQ3nz4dfjj8ePTEfLy8PPz45vLu6Ojg4cvd_dNXPhlXn__y3X4iv__v7_--Or7e_s7Tfx1cHU-rk93fTqbVy79v_21nmlan499OM3o66NNnLH10-5nx6Wl1li1n9oVn4zuPd0b7jbPxzScv9vjZs_zL-w_7SLa_nwczrc7Nfl6HeJ5HebJD6sDP89hPXyiZznme0fH4ojrJ8zzP8V0y9fM8-5P0XbIg53kNYlB5mc5tpWJQsHjb9bL1m1brSq1xYde2tqc7EFd8bYt-9sL6VqxtN07Gl-IerW2bxvf65q1t_07T9_qurm1jY7C23Wvb8eM8WDwHazsK46v9gKztjOTx-slZ2-HJ45UjtbZTdaLj9bO2tuMWi2uHcG3nUBbXTufaTqMsbj6263pyZXH5PG_Pbz3S02qD7KY77pt64s92eOcKm-oN5y-fADfZVE85HT_QudCmetH4DXCvTfWws_Qb4Hqb6n0xieqWm-qZJ3kSnctuqteOnwF33lSPzvMAV99Ub8_z8DAw5iGGPA8IEZsaJWIzavjY1Agim1FDy6ZGF9kMCzub7BzDIJvRhaRNjUrjlyBcbWrEylOBULap0SxPxcPcmIoY8lQgBG5qFMz74eFx7IcY8n546Bz7IYa8HxJW836EwfYDQu6mRt1wjhqONzUii3PUUL2p0Vqcw8J4OEc2iHPUEL-pUV6cw8J_OEc2iHNYagjnyAZxjpw2xDmGwZ2jTSnb_IFZZVrN3SfmhaQzY945331oISfNmJbWL5_jlDVj1jobP7aQ0WZMauP3OOHNmPPO0-9xPpwxJcbkMF3OmDFP8-QWsumMCXX8JCfbGfNtnh_n4hnTcZ4fpOoxP7fl-XEmnzGZx-Zhop8x18vmYR0wYykgm1fLhDn7X7bJ5i1UETMWEuNXuciYsc7IU-QaZMYyJE8RSpQxRbflKXIFM2MRk_cPCpyxf27L-wf1z9g_t-X98_Io75_YbP-4epqxgArnw-JqxvpKnA9rrxnLL3G-WpqF85lNnA8rtxmLN3G-WtiF85lNnK_WfeF8ZhPns7JQnC_b3PkWqsYZC8fxw1xUzlhX5llyzTlj2ZlnCSXpmKXb8iy5Yp2xaM1bCAXt2EK35S2EendsodvyFno5nLdQbLaFXC3PWDBn_4Nievif27L_Qa09_M9t2f-8FM_-JzbzP6jUh_-5LfufF_LZ_8Rm_ud1fvY_sZn_SRtg_he26n_cJczYKETywyZixj5Ckh_2GDO2GZL8agsSyc9skvywQ5mxSZHkVxuYSH5mk-RX-5tIfmaT5GftjyS_bPPkh93RjA2SJL_aPEXyM5skv9pbRfIzmyQ_a70k-WWbJ7_amUXyM5skP2vcJPllmyc_6-sk-WWbJ7_c9nnyGzZIfktd4bb_6xrDaXWx8LmLabF1fDJz97jefbQzb14-zf3l5uXTbft5sVsANF-Mzajmdfpt7lHHb7ct7O632Tx-u21yLybqZc_ypNEck0bzRT7xZj7XeXOvPH6-baV3P8_m8fNts72bN5vHvLkdH_MGc55327BfTNR7y2ajOTYbzRfZe80sm43mi-zfZpbNrmbZ7GlROLhADSBPvZUWdiNg8xhBKz7sps7mMXWWJ8bUwZyn3goYu_1m89hvljjGfoM57zeLIGO_wZz3G2SSvN9utv1uhZSLiTQRcW40h3OjOZy7msW50RzOXc3i3NUszj01gs7FyILVHM5dzeLc1SzOPZEoFM5dzeLcU5GNxLnN7M49LQpLF6gR5dm30tNuEGweg2jFqd3s2Txmz_LVmD2Y8-xbgWu35WweW84S2NhyMOctZ5FsbDmY85aDjJa33M225a3QtvNvNg__Zilu-DeYs3-zWDf8G8zZv0HOy_7tZvNvFvyGf4M5-zdIgtm_3Wz-DaJh9m83m3-7rGj-Lebq363weDGRhijJG82RvNEcybuaJXmjOZJ3NUvyrmZJ3mb25I3mSN7VLMm7miV5m9mTdzVL8jazJ28ze_LOZkjeaI7kXc2SvKtZkreZPXlXsyRvM3vyNrMn72yG5F3NkrzN7MnbzJ68sxmSt5k9eWczJO9shuQ9zNx8d9r0GEcrXe_GweYxjlbc3i0Am8cCsPw9FgDMeQFagXy362weu84S-th1MOddZ5F97DqY866DDJ933c22661Qv3NxNg8XZyl_uDiYs4uz2D9cHMzZxeE6ILu4m83F-cJguDiYs4vDlUJ2cTebi8OlQ3ZxN5uL-7WEubiYq4u3Fxe7_M3mkb_5amPkbzDn_M2XHyN_gznnb7geyfnbzZa_-QJl5G8w5_wNVyw5f7vZ8jdcwuT87WbL335NY_lbzDV_80XOyN9gzvkbrnpy_naz5W-4DMr5282Wv_26yPK3mGv-hgulnL_dbPnbr5wsf4u55m-_lLL8Leaav-XaqubvMGP-bi-2Lqbmbiua7-7qa998ozma7-5ybN98ozmab7w-i-a7mqX57i7Y9s03mqP5xiu4aL6rWZpvvKSL5ruapfmu13jSfJvZm-_uom_ffKM5mm-8Cozmu5ql-cbLwmi-q1ma73qdKM23mb35xgvHaL6rWZrveiUpzbeZvfmul5bSfJvZm2-71vTmO5uh-e4uPvfNN5qj-car0Wi-q1mab7w8jea7mqX5rter0nyb2ZtvvICN5ruapfmuV7TSfJvZm-96iSvNt5m9-bZrXm--sxmab7wIjua7mqX5rlfF0nyb2ZvvepkszbeZvfm262ZvvrMZmu96IS3Nt5m9-bYra2--sxmab7vU9uY7m6H5ztfe0HwPMzfff3Ax_vSVS3fjT5_-Yfnjxz9Mf3SFvkXaa_TN_isWkHl8S3vbPo9vWbqQfx7IAvIykA7Z5LG0d_cxlqXr_f1YWiTGsvQK4HlRFpCXRemQtCgdkhYFkbWtS_uuIIaz9PRgP5wWieEsvVDYr0uLxLq0DxliXRiRdVl67_B8WBaQl8PSIemwdEg6LIjoYemQdFgQ0cOCiB6WipTgMvXvMWJES0829iNqkRjR0suO_dK0SCxN-wAkloYRWZqldyL789IicV7a5yRxXhiR89K-OonzwoicF36cIucFED8vS29YnoPLAvISXDokBZcOScEFEQ0uHZKCCyIaXBDR4FKRElw6JAUXRDS4IKLBpSIluCCiwaUiJbhUpASX6Y_e_mw_0b7_iUEtPRHaD6pFYlBLL4n2q9MisTrtg6NYHUZkdZbeJe2PTIvEkWmfL8WRYUSOTPvKKY4MI3Jk-DGUHBlA_MgsvZnax5cWifjSPq2K-MKIxJf2BVbEF0YkvvBDLYkvgHh8ad9zRXxhROILP_uS-AKIxxd-HSbxBRCPL_CIzOOLIxBflt6aPRcvC8hL8dIhqXjpkFS8IKLFS4ek4gURLV4Q0eKlIqV46ZBUvCCixQsiWrxUpBQviGjxUpFSvFSkFC-GUPHSIal4QUSLF0S0eKlIKV4Q0eKlIqV4qUgpXgyh4gURLV4qUoqXipTixRAqXipSihdDqHgxhIqXjDTiy9S_b4xxLT2B3I-rRWJcSy8l9wvUIrFA7YPKWCBGZIGW3l3uT02LxKlpn2fGqWFETk37ijNODSNyavixp5waQPzULL0J3YeYFokQ0z4djRDDiISY9oVphBhGJMTwQ1QJMYB4iGnfq0aIYURCDD9rlRADiIcYfv0qIQYQDzHwSNZDjCMQYpbe0u7rlxaJ-qV9chv1CyNSv7Qvc6N-YUTqF37AK_ULIF6_tO98o35hROoXfg4s9QsgXr_wq2GpXwDx-gUeF3v94gjUL-0b5KhfGJH6hZ8qS_0CiNcv_KJZ6hdAvH6Bh89evzgC9Qu_j5b6BRCvX-AZtdcvjkD9Aq-tvX5xBOoXf5QN9YsgXL8svd1-Fl8WkBfxpUOS-NIhSXxBRMWXDkniCyIqviCi4ktFivjSIUl8QUTFF0RUfKlIEV8QUfGlIkV8qUgRXwwh8aVDkviCiIoviKj4UpEiviCi4ktFivhSkSK-GELiCyIqvlSkiC8VKeKLISS-VKSIL4aQ-GIIiS8ZacSXDkniCyIqviCi4ktFiviCiIovFSniS0WK-GIIiS-IqPhSkSK-VKSIL4aQ-FKRIr4YQuKLISS-ZKQRXxBR8aUiRXypSBFfDCHxpSJFfDGExBdDSHzJSCO-VKSIL4aQ-GIIiS8ZacQXQ0h8yUgjvmSkEV8G0j9-mfr_fUoMrUViaC0SQ2NE1qhFYo0YkTViRNYIED84LRIHhxE5OIzIwQHEDw4jcnAA8YMDiB8cRyDKtEhEGUYkyjAiUQYQjzKMSJQBxKMMIB5lHIEow4hEGUA8ygDiUcYRiDKAeJRxBKKMIxBlBOESpkWihGFEShhGpIQBxEsYRqSEAcRLGEC8hHEEShhGpIQBxEsYQLyEcQRKGEC8hHEEShhHoIQRhEsYRqSEAcRLGEC8hHEEShhAvIRxBEoYR6CEEYRLGEC8hHEEShhHoIQRhEsYR6CEEYRLGEG4hAmk1V9aJPQXRkR_YUT0F0Bcf2FE9BdAXH8BxPUXR0B_YUT0F0BcfwHE9RdHQH8BxPUXR0B_cQT0F0FYf2FE9BdAXH8BxPUXR0B_AcT1F0dAf3EE9BdBWH8BxPUXR0B_cQT0F0FYf3EE9BdBWH8RhPWXQFr9hRHRXwBx_QUQ118cAf0FENdfHAH9xRHQXwRh_QUQ118cAf3FEdBfBGH9xRHQXwRh_UUQ1l8CafUXQFx_cQT0F0dAfxGE9RdHQH8RhPUXQVh_CaTVXxwB_UUQ1l8EYf0lkFZ_EYT1l0Ba_SWQVn_ZI634crKA7L-0RWJcLRLjYkQWqEVigRiRBWJEFggQPzUtEqeGETk1jMipAcRPDSNyagDxUwOInxpHIMS0SIQYRiTEMCIhBhAPMYxIiAHEQwwgHmIcgRDDiIQYQDzEAOIhxhEIMYB4iHEEQowjEGIE4fqlRaJ-YUTqF0akfgHE6xdGpH4BxOsXQLx-cQTqF0akfgHE6xdAvH5xBOoXQLx-cQTqF0egfhGE6xdGpH4BxOsXQLx-cQTqF0C8fnEE6hdHoH4RhOsXQLx-cQTqF0egfhGE6xdHoH4RhOsXQbh-CaQVX1okxBdGRHxhRMQXQFx8YUTEF0BcfAHExRdHQHxhRMQXQFx8AcTFF0dAfAHExRdHQHxxBMQXQVh8YUTEF0BcfAHExRdHQHwBxMUXR0B8cQTEF0FYfAHExRdHQHxxBMQXQVh8cQTEF0FYfBGExZdAWvGFERFfAHHxBRAXXxwB8QUQF18cAfHFERBfBGHxBRAXXxwB8cUREF8EYfHFERBfBGHxRRAWXwJpxRdAXHxxBMQXR0B8EYTFF0dAfBGExRdBWHwJpBVfHAHxRRAWXwRh8SWQVnwRhMWXQFrxJZBWfEnI818aFeb6YPd_XP9_)

Takes a numpy array and modifies it in-place. Pretty straight-forward algo.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Z¡нθO@ÏÂ‡
```

Port of [the approach *@l4m2* used in his JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243082/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6tDCC3vP7fB3ONx/uOlRw8L//6MNdYx1THUMDXQsdSx0zHXMdEx0jGIB) or [verify the test cases up to length 6](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9vc2FiaWX/NkzOt3Z5P3nFk3YiIOKGkiAiP3nDkMOQ/1rCodC9zrhPQMOPw4LigKH/w68/fcK2LP8) (because any more will be too big for TIO's STDOUT).

**Explanation:**

```python
          #  e.g. input=[1,3,5,10,9,8,7,6,4,2]
Z         # Get the maximum of the (implicit) input-list
          #  STACK: [1,3,5,10,9,8,7,6,4,2],10
 ¡        # Split the input-list by this maximum
          #  STACK: [[1,3,5],[9,8,7,6,4,2]]
  н       # Leave the first list of the pair (the items before the maximum)
          #  STACK: [1,3,5]
   θ      # Leave the last value of that list (the value just before the maximum)
          #  STACK: 5
    O     # Sum in case the maximum was the very first item, resulting in 0
          #  STACK: 5
     @    # Check for each value in the (implicit) input-list if it's >= this item
          # before the maximum
          #  STACK: [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
      Ï   # Only leave the items of the (implicit) input-list at the truthy positions
          #  STACK: [5,10,9,8,7,6]
       Â  # Bifurcate this list (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy)
          #  STACK: [5,10,9,8,7,6],[6,7,8,9,10,5]
        ‡ # Transliterate the values in the (implicit) input-list, basically reverting
          # the part that was truthy earlier
          #  STACK: [1,3,6,7,8,9,10,5,4,2]
          # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: I don't think you're actually using @l4m2's approach; yours is better, in that it saves me a byte in my Retina answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 56 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 49 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with a `\`.

```r
function(v){v[i]=rev(v[i<-v>=sum(v[which.max(v)-1])]);v}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtNCsIwGAX3niLgJh@8iGn8K5pepGQhwdAs2kJtoyCePaahUNzNPOYN0enops6Ovu94oE@ovdHDI/AENxEq/ZzaxK/G22bX3t@pEdKQoWv4Rsctl0RbJipWS7PJDlYQZSzA5ILzCqZWU3@ZWkuVy9mWVOEIuUeJC8444YD0iz8)

Port of [@l4m2's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243082/55372) with the help of [@Kevin Cruijssen's explanation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243088/55372).

Answer (score 2):

## 80386 machine code, <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```
\x60\x8d\x1c\x91\x89\xde\x83\xee\x04\x8b\x06\x89\xd1\x29\xc1\x39\xd0\x75\x05
\x48\x01\xd1\xeb\x03\x89\xd0\x41\x89\xf7\xe2\x0e\xa5\x40\x89\x46\xfc\x83\xef
\x08\x39\xf7\x77\xf4\x61\xc3\x83\xc7\x04\x39\xdf\x74\xd2\x39\x07\x75\xce\x48
\xeb\xe2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJhb5swEP0Mv@LENNVukwpImqQimbTfEaLIGDuxSk0FzkpX8deX3WHSdmsl4A7u3bt3z8jpQcrzN2NldSoVrFtXmvr2@OO83wvnGlOcnNrvGWuVdKa2LLp1qnMR5xzkUTRQGLvdwSaM8m4R592qzLtE5t19gvl93pUK4yzvFMZ4jnmBcTHWEJNilBhn9I79yzus30VEN19hmniYorbZ2Iaw@Uivl1hLsYb0Alvnsf8@xxFajqP1QBev/BRqWeKtUc0CaeTMw@TSKxyUaMRgXqb@PV56ZVKRrIGOFKk0yv73SYvWSVFV6M@v2pTArp/N4VApzox1cD0BDBw25FsWhq0TzkiPfGqw9LNpxIuHigELlsNrGDydHNnNrl6veBYGum5gQBmkirNswAQDg2bR9zKagNiaHUEDo4Hd3CBwM3IFxNayqI@GelA0SjxQ1uOtfW0CeOG/UJ8cgfqw/1esX8o/2btMysTW7jKfkjpcMyjrYS5Kgikk@LuAIVJ4PppKAZtODQ35YADubukTESSwXoOlxnemcfAF9lXrJ/aLg7klC3EfUvgojGXe4TfzoHhxqs1tbtEDWo635reqNcMz46Tj0wkkGYY1xjgDtJp/0HixyLsYNMqdGotHFvbnP1JX4tCep4@z9C8)

Thanks to @l4m2 suggesting `pusha`/`popa` saving 4 bytes!

**assembly (nasm)**

```
wiggle: ; fastcall, ecx = pointer to array, edx = length of array
    pusha
    lea ebx, [ecx + edx * 4]
    mov esi, ebx
.L0:
    sub esi, 4
    mov eax, [esi]
    mov ecx, edx
    sub ecx, eax
    cmp eax, edx
    jne .0
    dec eax
    add ecx, edx
    jmp .1
.0:
    mov eax, edx
    inc ecx
.1:
    mov edi, esi
.L1:
    loop .2
.L2:
    movsd
    inc eax
    mov [esi - 4], eax
    sub edi, 8
    cmp edi, esi
    ja .L2
    popa
    ret
.2:
    add edi, 4
    cmp edi, ebx
    je .L0
    cmp [edi], eax
    jne .L0
    dec eax
    jmp .L1
```

Comment: f you want to protect registers, why not `pushad/popad`?

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 299 bytes

```javascript
f=(i,L=0,N=i.map((E,I)=>i.map(G=>I<G|0)).reverse(),Y=Q=>Q.map((e,j)=>Q.reduce((A,g,h)=>A+Q[h][j],0)),F=d=>i[N[L].indexOf(1)-d]&&i[N[L].lastIndexOf(1)-d]&&!(X=N.map((E,I)=>I>L?E:E.map((G,H)=>i[H+d]?E[H+d]:0))).some((E,I)=>E.some((G,H)=>i[I+1]&&G&!X[I+1][H]))&&X)=>F(1)?Y(F(1)):F(-1)?f(Y(F(-1)),L+1):i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVFNj4IwEL3zK@qFtHEkuh8X3WLMBpWEuPG0GsKBQMGaCqagu2bX3@4OIln01L55M@@9abfhMSwiLfdlL8tjcbkknErweB8WXFq7cE@pAy7jdg1m3HbfZr99xiwtjkIXgjJY8yW3l3WzgC2rgBbxIRKUTiCFDVYm3aW/CfxtADgLUx6jor/wvcCSWSy@PxI6YL04MM1bVYVF6d4zHbrii3Yk1/bGztCpSzOYVyn9eTcOxs71GKIVs4p8J5oJ54aaZrc7QOGZ2Vldr/48YMw0V8hN0XW8ptXBhlPaQ5TQCuONgdcdsKG8RHlWlCQ5KPUp01SJ91OkBOGE5lqmMguVJ4sSSHTQWmRlBZBsc4xwm/wYpBb6uorE2JPQ1gwb1Q25EpbKU3prq8oyIQ20qu844QcoIPikV2WhCL839JHCHStPokV50Fnjimpno6k9rPSwz3@As2HU0WUmS1nzGN8fAHkB8grkGchTMDLa8VutqPDodMde/gA)

Yes, I know. Not the shortest. Not anywhere close. However, this answer actually performs the wiggling steps by moving layers left and right.

Builds the list of layers, then attempts to move the current (`L`) layer to the left. If no layer is hovering in midair (some part is above empty air), then we return the resulting arrangement, otherwise we attempt to move to the right. If it is possible, recall `f` with incremented `L`, otherwise, because of the way the wiggling works, we are at the bottom layer and we simply return `i` unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```
\d+
*
^|$
,
V`,?(_*),(?=(_+)(?!.*\2))(?<!\2.*)(_+\1,)+
^,|,$

_+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYu7DsIwDEV3/0WlgPK4iuQkIyhj/4ApaooEAwsDYuy/B2O1i@/r@PP8vt53Hic7r6M9AnlaNkOg24pqu3ew9Wp7cLZO0bfkxFymlqJ30jaGC7RggyHqgUw8j8HESJSgiiw3a87SiDt6FNWyE0UY/qedLcLpql9F/3QF/wA) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 1 byte by using @KevinCruijssen's approach. Explanation:

```
\d+
*
^|$
,
```

Convert the unary and wrap the height map in an extra pair of `,`s.

```
V`,?(_*),(?=(_+)(?!.*\2))(?<!\2.*)(_+\1,)+
```

Get the number preceding the largest number in the input (or `0` if it's the first number), and reverse the sublist of all numbers equal to or exceeding that number. (Excepting `n,n-1,...,1`, valid inputs always contain a sublist of the form `k,n,n-1,...,k+1`.)

```
^,|,$

_+
$.&
```

Remove the extra `,`s and convert to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
≔⌕θ⌈θη≔⊕⌕θ⊕∧η§θ⊖ηζＩ…θ⊖ηＩ⮌✂θ∧η⊖ηζ¹Ｉ✂θζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY09D4IwEIZ3f8WNJTkHvwcngjFhMDE6EoamXGwTKNIiQf58LYbg5w033PM@9wrJjSh57lxorbpotlc6YxXCgbequBWsCgIEGWwnA4@1MFSQrikbs@@30J8kQljHOqO2pzt6URk8B6HzH49G6ZpF3Pp1FzlFsrz@FT6iJ2rIWGLnXAnq40Pjl@UrEGY/9mh1PXEuSWYIc4QVwgZhjbBEWKSpmzb5Aw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses @KevinCruijssen's approach.

```
≔⌕θ⌈θη
```

Get the index of the largest element.

```
≔⊕⌕θ⊕∧η§θ⊖ηζ
```

Get the index of the successor of the element one greater than the predecessor of the largest element, or the length of the array (calculated as the index after the position of the `1` which is always last in that case) if the largest element is the first element.

```
Ｉ…θ⊖η
```

Output the elements up to the predecessor of the largest element.

```
Ｉ⮌✂θ∧η⊖ηζ¹
```

Output the elements not less than the predecessor of the largest element, but in reverse.

```
Ｉ✂θζ
```

Output the remaining elements.